# OrientDb how to not update links when using the object database

Tags: java, orientdb

Hello I have an Object Database in OrientDb, I am currently opening and closing my connections to the database after getting the data I need, for this reason I am using a fetchplan *:-1 and detaching my pojos using .detachAll(entity, true).

For example:

```
public <T extends NamedEntity> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass) {
    db= pool.acquire(connectionString, user, password);
            db.getEntityManager().registerEntityClasses("com.mypackage");
    List<T> l= new ArrayList<T>();
    OObjectIteratorClass<T> it= db.browseClass(entityClass);
    if (it == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("entityClass " + entityClass.getName() + "not browseable by OrientDb");
    it.setFetchPlan("*:-1");
    for (T entity : it) {
        l.add((T) db.detachAll(entity, true));
    }
    db.close();
    return l;
}
```

The problem is when I try to .save() these guys back to the database I get a version conflict if two of the entities both have links to a third entity. This happens because when I save the first one the link is also saved because of the detachAll call so when I save the second entity the link is also going to be saved again but this second entity link is in a version one below the current one (even though I did not touch the link at all.)

Like this:

```
List<MyClass> l= findAll(MyClass.class);
//assuming the list contains two elements
MyClass my1= l.get(0);
my1.setLink(myLinkedClass);
MyClass my2= l.get(1);
my2.setLink(myLinkedClass);
db.save(my1);
db.save(my2);
```

So what I am asking is, is there any way to save a pojo without also saving the links? Any special method call I can use to say to OrientDb: "Hey don't look *into* the links when saving this pojo, look only at their RIDs"?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the linked objects first, then the main object. In this way OrientDB will find the object non-dirty and will skip the cascading save.

Comment: That would work on my simple example, but it would not work on most of the other cases I have (when I load some entities and set a non-link field in all of them for example). What I actually want is to not have to handle the links at all.

Comment: Also I think I found a bug, OObjectLazySet.contains(null) or OBjectLazySet.remove(null) are giving null pointer exception (it seems OrientDb is trying to serialize the nulls). Since they implement Set those methods calls should work.